# How to export a context from a class component in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having problems in export a Context from a Component.
The component that holds the context is below.

```
import React, { Component, createContext} from 'react';


export const MyContext = React.createContext('');

export default class ComponentOne extends Component {
   ....
   ....
   render(){
     return(
     <MyContext.Provider value={'value1'}>
      <div>....</div>
     </MyContext.Provider>
     )
   }

}
```

The component that wants to import the Context is below

```
import React, { Component}  from 'react'
import { MyContext } from "../ComponentOne/Index.js"

export default class ComponentTwo extends Component{
render(){
  console.log(this.props)
  return(
    <MyContext.Consumer>
    </MyContext.Consumer>
  )
}
}
```

The Error I'm getting is

`TypeError: render is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

Context Provider requires a children.

```
 <MyContext.Provider value={'value1'}>
    <ComponentTwo />
  </MyContext.Provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

The context is available to `MyContext.Provider` children.

In your case, you need to render `ComponentTwo` within the provider, and as a consumer, read the `value` provided:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export const MyContext = React.createContext('');

class ComponentTwo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext.Consumer>{value => <div>{value}</div>}</MyContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}

class ComponentOne extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext.Provider value={'value1'}>
        <ComponentTwo />
      </MyContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ComponentOne />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The error might be because of not reading the value inside the `Context.Consumer`.

Reference: [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#api).

[image: Edit react-antd-styled-template]